# Where to find information on exceptions thrown by classes and methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am trying to add more specific error handling to my c# app, but I am finding it hard to track down what exceptions are thrown by classes and method. Is there a way through visual studio 2010 to find this info, or maybe an exception list?

Comment: Do you mean, for a given method or code statement you want to know which exceptions it might throw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find the class/method you are interested in on MSDN.

For example, look at this page for [the Dictionary.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx). If the method throws an Exception (like this one), you can get the information for the **Exceptions** section of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about .Net framework methods, they are documented in the hover over help.  You will see Exceptions: .  Or you can see it in the object browser Ctrl+W, J as well.  Or press F1 over a function to go to MSDN help, where they are documented in detail.

Comment: I am using the productivity extension and for some reason that information isn't shown

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowing the exceptions to be thrown, you should be able to see the exception details in the Event Viewer in Administrative Tools.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of exceptions that a class might throw?

Answer (score 0):

You can find specific uses of a particular exception, but there is no complete listing of all exceptions any method might throw.

Consider the following method:

```
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
       SomeObject x = null;
       x.SomeMethod(); // NullReferenceException

       File.Open("SomePath", FileMode.CreateNew); // Any number of File Exceptions potentially

       throw new CustomException();
  };
```

How would a code analyzer be able to determine which potential exceptions there were?

If you're looking for information on a specific class, I'd check the documentation for it.

Comment: It would just have to analyze SomeMethod and File.Open recursively and give you at least list of all the possible exceptions. It doesn't matter if they actually can occur, but at least a list instead of me manually parsing through tons of code.